# Naming a method that gets the next enum value or starts from the beginning if the given value is the last

Tags: c#, enum, extension-methods, circular-list

I'm struggling to find a proper name for a specific method (in code named `NameOfExtension`), and would also like some feedback about its implementation.

I am writting an extension method that must return the next enum value given a specific enum item (order is given by `GetValues` method). If it reaches the end, it should continue from the beginning:

```
public static T NameOfExtension<T>(this T enumItem) 
  where T : Enum
{
  List<T> items = GetValues<T>().ToList();
  int idx = items.IndexOf(enumItem);
  if (idx + 1 < items.Count)
  {
    return items[idx + 1];
  }

  return items[0];
}
```

Since we are using an old version of .Net framework (4.72) and can't use .Net6 right now, I had to implement this extension as well:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
  where T : Enum
{
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `(idx + 1) % items.Count` to reach the answer?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: `NextEnumValue`, `SubsequentValue`, `ConsecutiveValue`, etc...

Comment: @PeterCsala True, I had previously thought of just calling it `Next` (Since it's already an extension method for a specific enum) but it was sort of difficult to differentiate the case where I want to get the first one if we are already in the last enum value. I didn't want to call the method something like `NextOrFirst`. Maybe calling it something like `NextInLoop`? or `CycleNext`?

Comment: @CiaPan looks nice. I'm curious if it would bring a benefit for code readablity, for example less variables, or something similar?

Comment: @c-chavez `NextInCyclicWay`, `CyclicNext`?

Comment: This is unexpected behavior for an Enum, so it violates the Principle of Least Surprise.  How about specializing Enum to a subclass CyclicEnum, and having `Next()` behave that way for your subclass? It's the same code, you're just structuring the class hierarchy differently, so that your users are surprised less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key phrase you're looking for here is [**cyclic(al)**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cyclic) (I prefer cyclic over cyclical but this is subjective). My suggestion is therefore `GetNextCyclicValue`.

You can also simplify your code by using the `%` modulo operator, as its output very neatly aligns with a zero-based index.

```
public static T GetNextCyclicValue<T>(this T enumItem) 
  where T : Enum
{
  List<T> values = GetValues<T>().ToList();

  int currentIndex = values.IndexOf(enumItem);
  int nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % values.Count;

  return values[nextIndex];
}
```

Or if you want to condense it:

```
public static T GetNextCyclicValue<T>(this T enumItem) 
  where T : Enum
{
  List<T> values = GetValues<T>().ToList();

  return values[(values.IndexOf(enumItem) + 1) % values.Count];
}
```

Comment: Currently the most useful for me, cycle is the word I was completely missing. I also added a second option as `GetNext<T>(this T enumItem, bool cycleElements)`.

Comment: @c-chavez: Beware of Boolean parameters. Which code is more readable? `myEnum = myEnum.GetNextOrThrow()` or `myEnum = myEnum.GetNext(false)`?

Comment: Actually I would try to avoid `ToList` completely and write the function something like
`var values = GetValues<T>(); while(true) { foreach( var value in values ) { yield return value; } }`. In this case, of course, it doesn't matter because `GetValues` always returns a finite list but I like to keep things as general as possible.

Comment: @CompuChip: It doesn't really optimize anything for the current answer as the necessity of `Count` means that you'll always need the full enumeration. Also, enums should not have a number of values that would come close to even posing a performance issue here.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a bit more concise version of your code

```
public static T ConsecutiveValue<T>(this T enumItem) where T : Enum
{
    var values = GetValues<T>().ToList();
    var consecutiveValueIdx = values.IndexOf(enumItem) + 1;
    return consecutiveValueIdx < values.Count ? values[consecutiveValueIdx] : values[0];
}

public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>() where T : Enum
    => Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
```

Or you could put the conditional logic inside the indexer operator if you wish

```
return values[consecutiveValueIdx < values.Count ? consecutiveValueIdx : 0];
```

Comment: "Consecutive" doesn't sound like the right terminology here.

Comment: @200_success I've posted this answer before it turned out that OP wants to emphasise the cyclic nature value. I left my suggested naming alternatives as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

This method has some counterintuitive behaviour in special cases:

- If the `enumItem` is not found in the list, then the method returns the first element of the list.
- If the list is empty, then it also tries to return the first element, and crashes.

I can't say exactly what the "right" behaviour should be — perhaps an exception?

Comment: interesting, but I thought I covered both cases when finding the values of `T`. Is there a possible way to call this extension method and get an empty list for example? I cannot think of any... If this case is possible, I would probably throw an exception, since it seems it shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: @c-chavez In C# this is a valid type declaration: `public enum MyEnum {};` So, yes this edge case could cause some problem.

Comment: @PeterCsala true, but how would you call the extension method?

Comment: @c-chavez `ExtensionClass.CyclicNext(new MyEnum());` or `var e = new MyEnum(); e.CyclicNext();`

Comment: @PeterCsala then adding the check and throwing an exception might be the best solution for this case.

Comment: @c-chavez Yes, that's what 200_success suggested

Comment: *adding the check and throwing an exception might be the best solution*  => best is an enum value for "undefined" - or "none" or whatever you want to call it.  Then initialize your enum variable to that.   It's just another enum value. Do whatever - ignore it, return early, make a "null object", but you should not have to stop execution with "OMG emergency!" exception code everywhere.  Hint: define `enum E { undefined = 0, ...)` "undefined" explicitly as zero - it will be the enum's default value.

Comment: @radarbob if there is a value inside the enum (for example `undefined` or `none`), then that value is valid, there is no need for an exception since what I want to find is the next value inside the enum's possible values. If you have i.e. `enum Values {Undefined, Value1, Value2}`, the next value of `Value2` would be `Undefined`, and the next value of `Undefined` is `Value1`. What we discuss in this thread is about those weird cases where you call the extension method with an empty or invalid input, and in that case the best solution is to throw an exception, since it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer you are asking, about naming, but this implementation contains some implementation ideas on performance and correctness.

Essentially, it collects all the enum values and puts them into a dictionary, mapping to the next enum value. Using a static constructor on a static class, and a static dictionary, this is only done once per enum type. This would be performant if the enum list is quite long.
After that, getting the next value is a matter of doing a dictionary lookup. If the value is not found an exception is thrown.

Static Class

```
public static class EnumMap<T>
where T : Enum
{
    static Dictionary<T, T> _map = new Dictionary<T, T>();
    
    static EnumMap()
    {
        var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToArray();
        
        for(int idx = 0; idx < items.Length; ++idx)
            _map[items[idx]] = items[(idx + 1) % items.Length];
    }
    
    public static T GetMapped(T value)
    {
        return 
            _map.TryGetValue(value, out var mappedValue)
                ? mappedValue
                : throw new Exception($"Invalid Enum value '{value}'.");
    }
}
```

Lookup Extension Method

```
public static T GetNextMapped<T>(this T enumItem)
  where T : Enum
{
    return EnumMap<T>.GetMapped(enumItem);
}
```